# IMemoryCache gets injected without adding it

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I have switched my application from MemoryCache to DistributedSqlServerCache. After commenting out services.AddMemoryCache(), I noticed that IMemoryCache gets still injected in my classes. I use aspnet-core 2.1.

The code that adds the cache to the services:

```
//services.AddMemoryCache();
services.AddDistributedSqlServerCache(o =>
{
    o.ConnectionString = ConnectionString;
    o.SchemaName = "dbo";
    o.TableName = "tbSessionCache";
});
```

Proof that it still gets inejcted:

[image]

Why does this happen? I think I may not get how this works. Thanks a lot!

Comment: MVC uses `IMemoryCache`, so it is still available even if you do not explicitly load it.

Comment: OK, the expected answer offers an explanation, but do you have a solution?  If so, post a self-answer.

Comment: I only searched for an explanation, which was provided in the accepted answer. If you want to prevent this behavior, I think you could create a interface that derives from IMemoryCache (e.g. IHttpCustomMemoryCache) and build a wrapper-service around IMemoryCache with it. Not sure if this is pretty though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MVC adds a default memory cache implementation when configuring the Razor view engine. It is consumed by the cache tag helper: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/17d2545b557863955cb5838fa16c6318931ac659/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor/DependencyInjection/MvcRazorMvcCoreBuilderExtensions.cs#L224.

Comment: Anything like a Remove or Clear in the std IO Container?